# Errors saving JSON data - NodeJS Express

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, express

I am having a problem saving and accessing my JSON data, all of the objects within the JSON file get converted to **string**, even numbers.

Here is my express route to `GET` data from the `HTML FORM`

```
control.post('/like/:id',getuserdata, async (req, res, next) => {
    try{
        let likedata = './bin/like/likedata.json'
        let title = res.accountuser.title;
        let pass = res.accountuser.password;
        let tags = req.body.likes;
        let actions = req.body.action;
        let like =  {
            username: title,
            password: pass,
            tag: tags,
            times: actions,
        }
        
        let jsonlike = JSON.stringify(like)
        fs.appendFileSync(likedata, jsonlike)
        next();
        res.redirect('/dashboard')
        } catch (err){
            console.log(err)
        }
});
```

This is how my JSON file comes when I add the value twice or more, the JSON file shows errors `End of file expected.`

```
{"username":"account1","password":"somepass1","tag":"hello","times":"5"}{"username":"account2","password":"somepass2","tag":"helllo","times":"444"}
```

**I want to use this JSON data individually, here:**

```
const ig = require('./like');
var cron = require('node-cron');

const iglike = async() => {

   await ig.initialize();

   await ig.login(username, password); //here

   await ig.liketagsprocess(tag, times); //here

};
cron.schedule('* */4 */12 * * *', function() {
   iglike();
});

module.exports = iglike;
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are writing to the JSON file is not a valid JSON at all.

```
// Contents of your file

{"username":"account1","password":"somepass1","tag":"hello","times":"5"}{"username":"account2","password":"somepass2","tag":"helllo","times":"444"}
```

Try this structure, which is an array of JSON objects:

```
[{"username":"account1","password":"somepass1","tag":"hello","times":"5"}, {"username":"account2","password":"somepass2","tag":"helllo","times":"444"}]
```

If you generate this data structure and and write this in a  `JSON` file the same way you are doing now, you won't get the error hopefully.

Also you should probably try to minimize the read/write ops `appendFileSync()` is a blocking op, you can load a valid `JSON` file using `require` and work on that, and periodically try and update the contents in the file by overwriting it the current state of the JSON array of objects.

Copy-paste the below code into a  file named `app.js` and run by typing `node app.js`, check the `console.log()` output and the `json` files generated. Results are self explanatory.

```
const like = require('./like.json');
const fs = require('fs');

const init = () => {
    console.log(like);
  
    let likedata = [
        {
            "hello": "world",
            "one": 1
        }, 
        {
            "hi": "there",
            "two": 2
        }
    ];

    let likedatastr = [
        {
            "hey": "whatsup",
            "three_str": "3"
        }
    ];

    let likedatamod = [
        {
            "hey": likedatastr[0].hey,
            "three_int": parseInt(likedatastr[0].three_str)
        }
    ]
    fs.writeFileSync('./likedata1.json', likedata);
    fs.writeFileSync('./likedata2.json', JSON.stringify(likedata));
    fs.writeFileSync('./likedatastr.json', JSON.stringify(likedatastr));
    fs.writeFileSync('./likedatamod.json', JSON.stringify(likedatamod));

};

init();
```

And `like.json` is as below:

```
[{"username":"account1","password":"somepass1","tag":"hello","times":"5"}, {"username":"account2","password":"somepass2","tag":"helllo","times":"444"]
```

Likewise, ensure that the numbers are really numbers in the data which you are extracting from the request body. Ideally you should to a `parseInt()` (assuming you expect integers) on the request body data which you expect to be numbers, and handle `NaN` just in case!

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your help!